# Make new array for json data

Tags: json

I have json file as below:

```
[
  {"TYPE": "A", "STATUS": "SUCCESS", "DISCOUNT": 500.00, "TOTAL": 5000.00},
  {"TYPE": "A", "STATUS": "SUCCESS", "DISCOUNT": 300.00, "TOTAL": 1266.00},
  {"TYPE": "A", "STATUS": "FAIL", "DISCOUNT": 300.00, "TOTAL": 515.00},
  {"TYPE": "B", "STATUS": "SUCCESS", "DISCOUNT": 323, "TOTAL": 846.00},
  {"TYPE": "B", "STATUS": "FAIL", "DISCOUNT": 80.00, "TOTAL": 3000.00},
  {"TYPE": "B", "STATUS": "KIV", "DISCOUNT": 105, "TOTAL": 900.00},
  {"TYPE": "C", "STATUS": "KIV", "DISCOUNT": 245.00, "TOTAL": 998.75},
  {"TYPE": "B", "STATUS": "SUCCESS", "DISCOUNT": 234.00, "TOTAL": 3500.00},
  {"TYPE": "C", "STATUS": "SUCCESS", "DISCOUNT": 201, "TOTAL": 5008.00},
  {"TYPE": "C", "STATUS": "FAIL", "DISCOUNT": 712, "TOTAL": 12300.00},
  {"TYPE": "A", "STATUS": "SUCCESS", "DISCOUNT": 500.00, "TOTAL": 5000.00},
  {"TYPE": "D", "STATUS": "SUCCESS", "DISCOUNT": 300.00, "TOTAL": 1266.00},
  {"TYPE": "D", "STATUS": "FAIL", "DISCOUNT": 300.00, "TOTAL": 515.00},
  {"TYPE": "D", "STATUS": "SUCCESS", "DISCOUNT": 323, "TOTAL": 846.00},
  {"TYPE": "B", "STATUS": "FAIL", "DISCOUNT": 80.00, "TOTAL": 3000.00},
  {"TYPE": "B", "STATUS": "KIV", "DISCOUNT": 105, "TOTAL": 900.00},
  {"TYPE": "C", "STATUS": "KIV", "DISCOUNT": 245.00, "TOTAL": 998.75},
  {"TYPE": "B", "STATUS": "SUCCESS", "DISCOUNT": 234.00, "TOTAL": 3500.00},
  {"TYPE": "C", "STATUS": "KIV", "DISCOUNT": 201, "TOTAL": 5008.00},
  {"TYPE": "C", "STATUS": "SUCCESS", "DISCOUNT": 712, "TOTAL": 12300.00} 
]
```

How to make:

1. Array of status
2. Array of total (sum total for each status)
3. Array number of each status

Example (Expected Result):

1) Status
   ["SUCCESS", "FAIL", "KIV"]

2) Total
   [199000.00, 12000.00, 6000.00]

3) Number of each status for each type such as:

```
[{A:[{SUCCESS: 2},
     {FAIL: 1}]
}, 
 {B:[{SUCCESS:2},
     {FAIL:1},
     {KIV:1}]
}]
```

I have tried my own way and its works (except no 3)but I want to know if it can be  another way to do which is more simple. 
Below is my step:

```
      var arrStatus=[];
      var countStatus=[];
      var flagStatus="";

      var arrTotal=[];

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var tempStatus = data[i].STATUS;

          flagStatus= false;

          for(var z = 0; z< arrStatus.length; z++){
            if(tempStatus == arrStatus[z]){

              arrTotal[z] += data[i].TOTAL;
              countStatus[z]++;
              flagStatus = true;

            }
          }              

          if(flagStatus == false){
            countStatus.push(1);
            arrStatus.push(tempStatus);
            arrTotal.push(data[i].TOTAL);
          }
      }
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: Assuming this is c#, you can utilize the Newtonsoft.Json library to parse the JSON string into a strongly-typed JObject. From that object, you can manipulate the data to generate a new JObject to your wishing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm. Create a map. The key would be a STATUS value. The value is an object of type say JsonData (a class you create), which has two properties: count and total. Iterate through your json data. If you encounter a new status, create a fresh instance of type JsonData and set its values accordingly (e.g., count = 1, total = 5000). If you encounter an already seen status, increment the count by one, and the total by the new total (e.g., count++ and total = total + 1266 for the second time you see a SUCCESS entry).

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution out there, but it works!

```
function getUnique(array, item) {
  var items = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    for (var key in array[i]) {
      if (key === item) {
        items.push(array[i][key]);
      }
    }
  }
  return eliminateDuplicates(items);
}

function eliminateDuplicates(arr) {
  var i,
    len = arr.length,
    out = [],
    obj = {};

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    obj[arr[i]] = 0;
  }
  for (i in obj) {
    out.push(i);
  }
  return out;
}
var uniqueStatus = getUnique(data, "STATUS");
console.log(uniqueStatus);
```

Ouput: `[ 'SUCCESS', 'FAIL', 'KIV' ]`

```
function getTotal(array, item) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    for (var key in array[i]) {
      if (array[i][key] === item) {
        sum += array[i]["TOTAL"];
      }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
var total = [getTotal(data, "SUCCESS"), getTotal(data, "FAIL"), getTotal(data, "KIV")];
console.log(total);
```

Output: `[ 38532, 19330, 8805.5 ]`

```
var uniqueType = getUnique(data, "TYPE");
console.log(uniqueType);
```

Output: `[ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ]`

```
function makeObject(array, type, status) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (array[i]["TYPE"] === type && array[i]["STATUS"] === status) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(makeObject(data, "B", "SUCCESS"));
```

Output: `3`